# [iOS]Does Image I/O cache decoded image when creating image source with CFDataRef?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, caching

I know I can create UIImages  with `[UIImage imageNamed:]` or other `UIImage` methods. I use Image I/O to create gif animation in my app. And resize images too since it's super fast!

In WWDC 2012 session: [iOS App Performance: Graphics and Animations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) , Apple engineer suggests that I shouldn't cache images myself because image caching is handled by system. From Apple's [Image I/O Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH216-TPXREF101) , one of features Image I/O provides is

> Effective caching

So I decided let Image I/O cache all images for me. There is a key named `kCGImageSourceShouldCache` in 
`Image Source Option Dictionary Keys` of which the description says

> Whether the image should be cached in a decoded form.

I believe if I create an image source with an url, then the images created later are cached. But what if the image source is created with a `CFDataRef` object? It's just a pointer to some image data, it's not like an url which can identify a unique resource. Does Image I/O still cache images in this case? Thanks.

Here is the code I used to create image:

```
CFDictionaryRef   myOptions = NULL;
CFStringRef       myKeys[2];
CFTypeRef         myValues[2];

myKeys[0] = kCGImageSourceShouldCache;
myValues[0] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
myKeys[1] = kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat;
myValues[1] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;

myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **) myKeys,
                               (const void **) myValues, 2,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                               & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(imageData, myOptions);
CFRelease(myOptions);
CGImageRef myImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);
CFRelease(imageSource);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments with Instruments, I finally figured this out. That is, if the caching option is turned on, image decoding only happens once, and it happens when the image is needed to be drawn the first time. As long as I keep the reference of the image, the decoded version of the image is cached. The source of image is not related.

Comment: Yes, some people actually found decoding slow and would even render image to offscreen 1x1 context on background thread to force decoding.